# Do minions/neutrals get stronger as the game goes on?

Tags: league-of-legends

Someone told me that as the game plays out longer, the jungle creeps and minions get stronger.

Is this true? 
& If so, how much time before they do?

Answer (score 11):

For minions:

> The blue and purple team minions spawn every 30 seconds from the Nexus
>   in order to support the champions. Minions begin spawning 1 minute 30
>   seconds after the game has begun. Every 3 minutes the minion waves
>   will grow stronger, with every type of minion gaining different stats.
>   Minions deal 50% more damage to turrets than they do to champions and
>   other minions.

---

> Once an enemy team's inhibitor is destroyed, the Nexus will start spawning Super Minions in the corresponding lane on the next wave, along with giving a boost of roughly 100hp to all the regular minions in all 3 lanes for future waves. Regular minions spawned while the inhibitor is down receive additional attack damage. Ranged and melee minions in all lanes receive a bonus amount based on the number of enemy inhibitors destroyed as their wave spawns.

I'm still searching for the actual numbers on the camps, but they do get stronger as the game progresses.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Minions)

Here is a [list of monsters](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Monster#List_of_Monsters) and their respawn timers. Clinking the hyperlinks will get you their individual stats.

I've found a couple of values that increase as time passes:

- **Dragon** gets more HP for champion levels: 3030 + 220 * (highest champion level) HP

**Baron**

- Gets more HP as time passes: 8852 + 125 every 1 min (Though patch V1.0.0.108 increased his base hp to 8000, so the 8852 base my be outdated).
- Starting health regeneration per second lowered to 15. Baron Nashor gains 0.375 health regen a second every minute. (Patch V0.9.25.34)

**Red buff:**

- 1372 (+90 per minute after spawn) HP
- 65 (+1.825 per minute after spawn)

**Blue buff:**

- 1372 (+90 per minute after spawn) HP
- 65 (+1.825 per minute after spawn)

Comment: Is there a limit to how strong the minions can get?

Comment: I've not found data saying what the cap would be, but I assume there is one at some point. If I happen on the stats I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as time goes on the Minions do more damage, Super Minions have increased health and damage, the neutral camps gain increased stats respectively, Dragon gains health and stats based on highest champion level and Baron gains health every x amount of time. Also, Turrets have increased stats as well.

Sources:
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jungling

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Minions

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Baron

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turrets